# Add a button in the main Gmail interface with an add-on

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail, gmail-api, gmail-addons

Is it possible to add, via a [Gmail add-on](https://developers.google.com/gmail/add-ons/) / Google Apps Script, a button on this part of the interface:

[image]

Note: I would like this to be present every time you open http://mail.google.com, no matter the browser, no matter if it's mobile/desktop, i.e. **without having to install a browser extension**.

I know it's possible to enhance the Gmail UI with [Cards](https://developers.google.com/gmail/add-ons/concepts/cards), but I'm not sure if it's possible to add buttons in this zone.

Comment: No so far Google has not released any APIs to integrate button on Gmail, however in their new design they have added cards directly in the new Gmail UI

Comment: I mentioned cards in the question @Vivek but i m not sure if it is possible with cards to add buttons there.

Comment: no it's not possible yet

Comment: You can add button here only via Chrome extension. 
Gmail add-on or Google Apps Script or Gmail UI with Cards have different concept – it never allow free manipulation with UI.

Comment: What is the closest we can get @Vivek? Where would be the buttons?

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible. Unless you're part of the Google Engineering team itself, you get to have your own button in the main Gmail UI.

Try adding a button in the message body. That's feasible.

Answer (score 0):

In short: **No**

Probably allowing this might mix up add-on's features and gmail's out of the box features. Users might find it difficult to differentiate between them.

**Mobile compatibility**

In case if they allow users to create a button there , they should come up with a solution to fit the button in android's gmail app as well. Which might clutter things up.